# The group $\mathbb{Q}$ of rationals can't be finitely generated - correct proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to prove that the group $\mathbb{Q}$ of rationals can't be finitely generated. Please judge my proof. Is it too informal?

---

The order of the group $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\aleph_0$, and so it is infinite. Suppose, however, that it still can be generated somehow from a finite group $G$, whose cardinality is $k$. Then
$$\left<G\right>=\{a_1^{e_1}*...*a_m^{e_m}\left.\right|\,a_i\in G, e_i=\pm 1, \,\, 1\leq m \leq k\}$$

But we have taken combinatorics before, and we know that this situation can be reformulated as the following illustration depicts.

[image]

As the illustration suggests, we know that the number of elements in $\left<G\right>$ is simply $3^k-1$, which is finite (i.e. less than $\aleph_0$). Contradiction.

---

**EDIT:** I think I may have pinpointed my misconception about generations of subgroups. I was under the impression that each element in a finitely-generated group had to be the product of a finite number of distinct elements in the group from which it is being generated from **with no repeating elements or an element *and* its inverse**. Basically, I thought $a^2$ couldn't be in there.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say at all. It's certainly not true that finitely generated subgroups of $\Bbb Q$ are finite.

Comment: Your illustration does not suggest *me* absolutely anything, I am afraid.

Comment: @MikeMiller could you expand on that?

Comment: Your mistake is in thinking that finitely generated means generated by a finite group (which makes no sense). By your argument the integers would not be finitely generated.

Comment: "A group is called *finitely generated* if it can be generated by a finite number of elements." That's exactly what my book says. Where in my faulty proof do I stray from this definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is false, because you assume that $e_i=\pm 1$ and that none of the $a_i$ are repeating in more than one block. This is not true in general, for instance you are allowed to have elements like $a_1^2a_2a_1a_3^3$ in the group. Also for an abelian group like $\mathbb{Q}$, it is better to think of the group operation as addition, rather than multiplication.

Moreover, your method of proof will not work because most finitely generated subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$ do in fact have the same cardinality as $\mathbb{Q}$! So a simple cardinality argument will not do.

I would suggest the following method, based on the infinitude of primes. If you fix a finite set of rationals, $S$, then there will be a large prime $P$ bigger than all prime factors appearing in elements of $S$. Then one may show that $1/P$ is not in the subgroup generated by $S$, contradiction.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean by "...you assume... that none of the $a_i$ are repeating in more than one block." I did assume that because the definition my book gave me made it seem that that was the case.